# Match and replace cell from another sheet

Tags: excel, match

I have no experience when it comes to this type of query and i'm stuck.

I've found a working query that i have used, here is the logic:

"If any cell in Sheet2 Column A = Any cell in Sheet1 Column B, change sheet2 column A cell value to sheet1 column A value"

The formula for this is:

```
Sub Test1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim cell As Range, varFind As Variant
With Sheets("Sheet1")
For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(1).SpecialCells(2)
Set varFind = .Columns(2).Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not varFind Is Nothing Then cell.Value = .Cells(varFind.Row, 1).Value
Set varFind = Nothing
Next cell
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

That works fine for me, but I need it slightly different. It needs to follow this logic:

"If any cell in Sheet2 Column A = Any cell in Sheet1 Column B, change sheet1 column A cell value to sheet2 column B value"

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[updated as I had needed to change the column on sheet 2 from A to B]

As you have writen this you would simply change this line

`If Not varFind Is Nothing Then cell.Value = .Cells(varFind.Row, 1).Value`

to

`If Not varFind Is Nothing Then .Cells(varFind.Row, 1).Value = cell.Offset(0,1).Value`

There is scope to improve this code speed if performance is an issue. Plus you will have a potential code bust if there are no constant cells in sheet 2 column B for SpecialCells to look at  .... pls advise if you'd like the code tweaked further

Comment: After further testing, it seems that it only changes one instance of the matched cell values. In my sheets there are multiple instances of the same values which need to be changed. Can it be modified to change all matches?